# Sheets is not defined Issue?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Really confused here - this script works in one document, but not in another.  I've tested out altering tab names, using an array vs. a bunch of if statements, really not sure where to go here.

Ultimately, all I want to do is add a row above row 30 on every tab in my document minus a few:

```js
function insertRow() {
   
   // Retrieve the spreadsheet
   const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var allsheets = ss.getSheets();
   
   var exclude = ["Sheet2", "Sheet5"];
   
   for(var s in allsheets){
      var sheet = allsheets[s];
    
      // Stop iteration execution if the condition is meet.
      if(exclude.indexOf(sheet.getName())==-1) continue;
    
      sheets[i].insertRowBefore(row);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert a row above row 30

```
function insertRowBefore30() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const shts = ss.getSheets();
  var exclude = ["Sheet2", "Sheet5"];
  shts.filter(sh => !~exlude.indexOf(sh.getName())).forEach(sh => sh.insertRowBefore(30));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Modification points:

- In your script, `sheets[i].insertRowBefore(row);` is required to be modified. `sheets`, `i`, `row` are not declaread.
- From `Ultimately, all I want to do is add a row above row 30 on every tab in my document minus a few:`, `insertRowBefore` might be `insertRowsBefore`.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
sheets[i].insertRowBefore(row);
```

#### To:

```
sheet.insertRowsBefore(1, 30);
```

- By this modification, 30 rows are inserted to the 1st row.
- If you want to insert 30 rows after the last row, please use `sheet.insertRowsAfter(sheet.getLastRow(), 30);`.

#### Note:

- From your showing script, I thought that you might want to use the specific sheets in `var exclude = ["Sheet2", "Sheet5"];`. And, from `I jwant to add a SINGLE row above row #30.. I was doing "30,1" and it wasn't working there either`, in this case, how about the following modification?

  - From

    ```
      sheets[i].insertRowBefore(row);
    ```
  - To

    ```
      if (sheet.getMaxRows() >= 30) {
        sheet.insertRowBefore(30);
      }
    ```
  - When the number of rows is less than 30, an error occurs. Please be careful about this.
- If you want to exclude the sheets `var exclude = ["Sheet2", "Sheet5"];`, please modify `if(exclude.indexOf(sheet.getName())==-1) continue;` to `if (exclude.indexOf(sheet.getName()) != -1) continue;`.

#### Reference:

- [insertRowsBefore(beforePosition, howMany)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertRowsBefore(Integer,Integer))

Comment: thanks for the response, I should've clarified --- my script simply isn't working at all as I am receiving the error "Sheets is not defined", whether i use "row" or the cell location. I jwant to add a SINGLE row above row  #30.. I was doing "30,1" and it wasn't working there either

Comment: @Anthony Madle Thank you for replying. About `"Sheets is not defined"`, in your showing script, `Sheets` is not used. And, I think that this error is due to that Sheets API is not enabled. So, in this case, I'm worried that your error is not related to your showing script. Because, when I tested your script by reflecting my proposed script, no error occurs. So, in this case, it is required to know your whole script.